# Turn off eslint warning / tell compiler that a dependency will not change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, eslint, use-effect

I am getting `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` warning.
In my example I forgot the *user* dependency, but I deliberately omit *channel* dependency (it will change only when I reload the page). I know I can suppress the warning with eslint-disable-next-line (or similar), but I would like to do this only for *channel*, not for *user*.

Is there any way to do this?

App.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

export const App = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState("Alice"); //may change in the UI
  const { channel } = useParams(); //will not change

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("User", user);
    console.log("someExternalApi(channel)", channel);
    /* SomeExternalApi(user, channel); */

    //forgot 'user' dependency, but 'channel' will not change
  }, [user, channel]);

  return <p>Ahoj, przygodo!</p>;
};
```

index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { App } from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/:channel">
          <App />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-cartwright-u8dq7

Comment: If it won't change, why would you omit it?

Comment: It may not change now, but there's no guarantee it'll never change. To avoid possibly using stale values in the future, you should design your hook so that it doesn't depend on things that you have to simply *assert* won't change, rather than tell it with confidence (by putting `channel` in the dependencies array). This is a very useful article: https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/

Comment: Is it possible to put `const { channel } = useParams(); ` inside the `useEffect` hook?

Comment: @DennisVash `SomeExternalApi` is in fact a fairly complex business logic with several other different callbacks, I need to put 'channel' dependency in each of them which seems hard to maintain.

Comment: @M-N It's not possible: `React Hook "useParams" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function. (react-hooks/rules-of-hooks)`

Comment: @M-N How to tell my component to ignore changes to `channel`?

Comment: You ask about the general case and not for specifics.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of turning off the linter **which is not advised**, you can use a reference from `useRef`.

Note that it is very uncommon practice, you should know exactly what you doing, if `channel` will not change, you shouldn't omit it.

```
export const App = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState("Alice"); //may change in the UI
  const { channel } = useParams();
  const channelRef = useRef(channel);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("User", user);
    console.log("someExternalApi(channel)", channelRef.current);
    SomeExternalApi(user, channelRef.current);
  }, [user]);

  return <p>Ahoj, przygodo!</p>;
};
```